# Remove Copyright Xcode

Tags: xcode

Ok this seems like a dumb question and probably is but I cannot figure it out. I recently became a registered developer with Apple and set up Xcode etc. Well when I create a new project in the comments at the top of my code it says copyright of my college. Now I do not remember giving my college credentials other than when I bought the mac but I cannot figure out how to change this to my name. Thanks anyone for the assistance; here is the code:

```
//
//  main.m
//  Test
//
//  Created by Jason Alholm on 10/19/11.
//  Copyright (c) 2011 St Petersberg College. All rights reserved. <------ needs changing.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What version of Xcode (the answer is different for Xcode 3 and Xcode 4) ?

Comment: Tryed to change the info in address book?

Comment: Given his use of @autoreleasepool, I'd say 4.2 is a safe bet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, Xcode will by default get your company/organization from the Address Book. I believe that if you remove the organization from your 'me' entry in Address Book, Xcode will switch to using your name.

Another (probably better) approach is to set the ORGANIZATIONNAME variable to whatever you like. [This page](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1759-how-to-change-mycompanyname-in-xcode-to-something-more-meaningful/) gives simple instructions:

```
defaults write com.apple.ProjectBuilder PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions '{ "ORGANIZATIONNAME" = "My Company";}'
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it, X-Code on this Mac integrates deeper the i thought lol

Answer (score 4):

You can change this by selecting the project in the left-hand project navigator, then selecting the file inspector in the right-hand utility pane, and altering the Organization field.

Comment: It will only change the value for future files of this project.

Comment: This is often what is required.  I work for several different clients each of which needs their own copyright notice.  Setting it globally is not always the correct thing to do.